# Why is the object property of my base class shared with all instances of subclasses?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand a behaviour I've recreated in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk1z1gdz/2/).

```
function BaseObject(){}
BaseObject.prototype.value = 1;
BaseObject.prototype.obj = {value:1};

BaseObject.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name + " - Value: " + this.value);
    console.log(this.constructor.name + " - ObjValue: " + this.obj.value);
};

BaseObject.prototype.add = function(i) {
    this.value += i;
    this.obj.value += i;
};

function Derivation1(){}    
Derivation1.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Derivation1.prototype.constructor = Derivation1;

function Derivation2(){}
Derivation2.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Derivation2.prototype.constructor = Derivation2;

var first = new Derivation1();
var second = new Derivation2();

first.log();
first.add(1);
first.log();
second.log();
```

The Output is:

```
Derivation1 - Value: 1
Derivation1 - ObjValue: 1
Derivation1 - Value: 2 <-- as expected
Derivation1 - ObjValue: 2 <-- as expected
Derivation2 - Value: 1
Derivation2 - ObjValue: 2 <-- Why is this two too and not 1?
```

The behaviour suggests, that object members get shared by all instances or are accessed in a static way, while primitive members each reside in their own instance.

Could someone shed some light about this?

Comment: Everything is shared 'by value', and the value of `BaseObject.prototype.obj` is a reference to an object. So all instances will reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's rather simple, really - the prototype isn't deep copied. All of your objects have the same instance of `obj`, because you never create a new `obj` for each of your objects.

Just use a constructor (or some init function, if you prefer) for mutable properties. It will save you a lot of trouble:

```
function BaseObject() {
  this.value = 1;
  this.obj = { value:1 };
}

BaseObject.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(this.constructor.name + " - Value: " + this.value);
  console.log(this.constructor.name + " - ObjValue: " + this.obj.value);
};

BaseObject.prototype.add = function(i) {
  this.value += i;
  this.obj.value += i;
};

function Derivation1(){
  BaseObject.call(this);
}

Derivation1.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Derivation1.prototype.constructor = Derivation1;

function Derivation2(){
  BaseObject.call(this);
}

Derivation2.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Derivation2.prototype.constructor = Derivation2;

var first = new Derivation1();
var second = new Derivation2();
var third = new Derivation1();

first.log();
first.add(1);
first.log();
second.log();
third.log();
```

Note the added `third` instance - if you add it to your code, you'll see it *also* shares the same `obj` instance. In effect, your `obj` is a "static property" - though it's not readonly, so you can replace it in any instance.

Another important thing is that you have to call the parent constructor manually in the derived constructor - `Object.create` creates an uninitialized object.